# How to adjust and clean a list of times, currently formatted as messy strings of times?

Tags: python, time, data-manipulation

We have a messy python list containing times, as strings, that we are working to clean up:

```
our_times = ['3:40 PM ', '11:07 PM ', 'Fri 8/06, 12:10 AM ', '11:10 PM ',
 '5:10 PM ', '6:05 PM ', 'Fri 8/06, 12:10 AM ', '8:05 PM ',
 '7:10 PM ', '11:05 PM ', 'Fri 8/06, 12:15 AM ', 'BOT 3RD: 0-1, 1 Out']
```

We need to roll the times back by 4 hours, while simultaneously handling the following issues:

- some elements (see last element) are not a date time. We can detect these by the lack of an `AM` or `PM`.
- some elements have a date prefix, which will always be of the form `Mon 2/01` where `2` is the month (1-12) and `01` is the day (1-31).

We are close but currently stuck, we have:

```
clean_times = [elem.strip() for elem in our_times]
pm_times = [elem.split(' ')[0] if elem.find('PM') > 0 else '' for elem in clean_times]
am_times = [elem.split(' ')[2] if elem.find('AM') > 0 else '' for elem in clean_times]
in_progress = [elem if elem.find('AM') == -1 and elem.find('PM') == -1 else '' for elem in clean_times]
new_times = [i + j + k for i, j, k in zip(pm_times, am_times, in_progress)]

new_times
['3:40', '11:07', '12:10', '11:10',
 '5:10', '6:05', '12:10', '8:05',
 '7:10', '11:05', '12:15', 'BOT 3RD: 0-1, 1 Out']
```

We are stuck at how to roll these back by 4 hours. In particular, for a time like `3:40 PM` which needs to be set to `12:40 AM`, handling this seems tricky. For this, we probably want to transform to the `am_times` and `pm_times` before creating `new_times`. What we're going for is:

```
new_times
['12:40 AM', '7:07 PM', '8:10 PM', '7:10 PM',
 '1:10 PM', '2:05 PM', '8:10 PM', '4:05 PM',
 '3:10 PM', '7:05 PM', '8:15 PM', 'BOT 3RD: 0-1, 1 Out']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you can avoid using string manipulations to parse dates and times and instead get them into `datetime` objects, it will be easier to avoid mistakes.

You could make use [`dateutil.parser`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html). If it can't parse the times, then just return the string.

Since your times are now real time objects, rolling back four hours is trivial — you just subtract the timedelta:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

def find_time(t):
    try:
        return parse(t.strip())
    except ValueError:
        return t

def format_time_with_delta(dt, delta):
    if not isinstance(dt, datetime):
        return dt
    return datetime.strftime(dt + delta, '%I:%M %p')


our_times = ['3:40 PM ', '11:07 PM ', 'Fri 8/06, 12:10 AM ', '11:10 PM ',
             '5:10 PM ', '6:05 PM ', 'Fri 8/06, 12:10 AM ', '8:05 PM ',
             '7:10 PM ', '11:05 PM ', 'Fri 8/06, 12:15 AM ', 'BOT 3RD: 0-1, 1 Out']


# times is a list of either datetime objects or strings
times = [find_time(t) for t in our_times]

res = [format_time_with_delta(dt, timedelta(hours=-4)) for dt in times]
```

result will then be a list like:

```
['11:40 AM',
 '07:07 PM',
 '08:10 PM',
 '07:10 PM',
 '01:10 PM',
 '02:05 PM',
 '08:10 PM',
 '04:05 PM',
 '03:10 PM',
 '07:05 PM',
 '08:15 PM',
 'BOT 3RD: 0-1, 1 Out']
```

If you don't want to use `dateutil.parser`, you could make a `find_time` function like this that tries known formats instead. However, you will need to keep track of the formats you expect. If it turns out you have additional string formats, you can just add them to the `formats` tuple:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def find_time(t):
    formats = ('%I:%M %p', '%a %m/%d, %I:%M %p')

    for f in formats:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(t.strip(), f)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return t
```